# Making two of 4 columns equal width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table (width: 100%) with 4 columns. Column 1 and 3 are set to a fixed width of 190px. I want the remaining two columns to be of equal width no matter how wide the table gets.  I've tried using `<colgroup style='width: 50%'>` for each grouping of two columns.  I've tried using the calc function `calc(50% - 190px)` on each of the table columns via css.  I've also used different combinations of max and min widths.  All attempts fail once one column is forced to grow due to content.  And the content is text, so it should wrap instead of override the width.  Here's my html and css.

css:

```
table, td {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.main_table {
  width: 100%;
}
td.fixed_column {
  width: 190px;
  background-color: red;
}
td.non_fixed_column {
  max-width: calc(50% - 190px);
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

html:

```
<table class='main_table'>
  <tr><td class='fixed_column'>1.1</td><td class='non_fixed_column'>2.1</td><td class='fixed_column'>3.1</td><td class='non_fixed_column'>4.1</td></tr>
  <tr><td class='fixed_column'>1.2</td><td class='non_fixed_column'>2.2</td><td class='fixed_column'>3.2</td><td class='non_fixed_column'>4.2</td></tr>
</table>
```

```css
    table, td {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      border: none;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table.main_table {
      width: 100%;
    }
    td.fixed_column {
      width: 190px;
      background-color: red;
    }
    td.non_fixed_column {
      max-width: calc(50% - 190px);
      background-color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<table class='main_table'>
      <tr><td class='fixed_column'>1.1</td><td class='non_fixed_column'>2.1</td><td class='fixed_column'>3.1</td><td class='non_fixed_column'>4.1</td></tr>
      <tr><td class='fixed_column'>1.2</td><td class='non_fixed_column'>2.2</td><td class='fixed_column'>3.2</td><td class='non_fixed_column'>4.2</td></tr>
    </table>
```

This gives me a perfect result... until one of the cells has content that causes one column to grow.  I don't care how tall a cell/row gets.

```css
    table, td {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      border: none;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table.main_table {
      width: 100%;
    }
    td.fixed_column {
      width: 190px;
      background-color: red;
    }
    td.non_fixed_column {
      max-width: calc(50% - 190px);
      background-color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<table class='main_table'>
      <tr><td class='fixed_column'>1.1</td><td class='non_fixed_column'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</td><td class='fixed_column'>3.1</td><td class='non_fixed_column'>4.1</td></tr>
      <tr><td class='fixed_column'>1.2</td><td class='non_fixed_column'>2.2</td><td class='fixed_column'>3.2</td><td class='non_fixed_column'>4.2</td></tr>
    </table>
```

I do not want to use javascript to resize the cells.  I don't understand the mechanics at work here!

Comment: Does your project have Bootstrap?

Comment: no. straight html

Comment: Is using html `table` elements for layout a requirement? Flexbox can do that exact layout pretty easy.

Comment: It's not a layout, really, its information/data display.  I have considered using other elements or using tables within tables, but I was certain there was a correct way to format the table structured as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `table-layout: fixed;`.

> table-layout: fixed; - Table and column widths are set by the widths
>   of table and col elements or by the width of the first row of cells.
>   Cells in subsequent rows do not affect column widths.

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

```css
table, td {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      border: none;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table.main_table {
      width: 100%;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }
    td.fixed_column {
      width: 190px;
      background-color: red;
    }
    td.non_fixed_column {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<table class='main_table'>
      <tr><td class='fixed_column'>1.1</td>
      <td class='non_fixed_column'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</td><td class='fixed_column'>3.1</td><td class='non_fixed_column'>4.1</td></tr>
      <tr><td class='fixed_column'>1.2</td><td class='non_fixed_column'>2.2</td><td class='fixed_column'>3.2</td><td class='non_fixed_column'>4.2</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: This works great for my example html, and I had actually tried this in my actual code. In my actual code,however, the first row is actually a header with a colspan of 4, which negates the ability to use the fixed table-layout...  Any suggestions to overcome this issue?

Comment: I've tried using colgroups to specify the widths before the header row, but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: I solved the problem by using the `<caption>` tag and styling it the same way I had the header row.  This enable the functionality of the code in this answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i have resolve your issue and the problem is you are using min-width, if you want to restrict any contend for the particular with then you need not to use min-width.

Kindly use `width` instead of `min-width`, my suggestion is mentioned below please try.

```
td.non_fixed_column {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: I have already tried using width, max-width, and min-width in multiple combinations.